# Compiling/calling Mathematica-generated .so from C

Tags: compile, librarylink

I'm trying to call a compiled function from a C program.
I am generating the static object

```
/home/fabio/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/test.so
```

through the *Mathematica* code

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
compiledfunction = Compile[{x, _Real}, x];
LibraryGenerate[compiledfunction, "test"]
```

then by using the source `test.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double compiledfunction(double);

int main(){
  double a=2e0;
  printf("%20.12e\n",compiledfunction(a));
  return 0;
}
```

How I should call the compiler to link with the static object above?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I *think* this won't be possible because compiled functions do need to access the Mathematica kernel.  Perhaps generating C code with `CCodeStringGenerate` and extracting the part that doesn't depend on Mma would be better?  Or you can access the full Mathematica kernel from C through MathLink.

Comment: I would like to compile a stand-alone object file. Surely, I do not need to access the whole M kernel. Let us say for example only the PolyLog function.

Comment: I've tried to compile with (test.so copied in the actual directory) icc test.so test.c

Comment: Yes, you do need the whole Mathematica kernel to use LibraryLink.  Otherwise you need to generate C code, remove the part that depends on the M kernel and use the rest in your project.  If you try to link the library as compiled by Mathematica, then you do need the whole kernel and you can't have a standalone project.  I might be wrong, but I find it very unlikely that what you are trying to do (just link the library) is possible.

Comment: You might be interested in [MathCode](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcode/) which should help in compiling into re-usable C++ code.  I've never used it myself and it's unfortunately not free.

Comment: What I said above may be incorrect, but I do not have a solution for you. **It's possible that you can use the code without the full Mathematica kernel after all**, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Indeed I know that FFTW use mathematica codelet, and It works without installing mathematica. So what is the trick to do that? Maybe am I only missing the right reference for `compiledfunction` in the C code? I am leaving the questions opened for further contributions.